# Retrieve the points contained in a selection with Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to check if the points in the chart are contained in predefined selections, so I've add a selection box with the proper configuration of the `layout` section:

```
var N = 100;

function randomArray() {
  var output = new Array(N);
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    output[i] = Math.random();
  }
  return output;
}

var myPlot = document.getElementById("plotly-graph");

var settings = [
  {
    mode: "markers",
    x: randomArray(),
    y: randomArray()
  }
];

var layout = {
  selections: [
    {
      type: "rect",
      x0: 0.1,
      x1: 0.2,
      xref: "x",
      y0: 0.1,
      y1: 0.2,
      yref: "y"
    }
  ]
};

var config = {};

Plotly.react(myPlot, settings, layout, config);
```

The problem is that the array of selected points is empty until I manually add another selection (using manual interaction with the selection tool from the taskbar).
After that, the points within all selections are correctly included in the array of selected points.
I would like to find a way to trigger this selection event programmatically, without having to use a manual interaction, is this possible? Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems you are trying to retrieve the points contained in an arbitrary rectangular shape (?, you might want to edit your post to make it clear). Note that the `plotly_selected` event is fired _after_ selection has occurred, one can use it to take action once a selection is available, but triggering the event manually passing to it a selection rectangle or whatever won't do anything (you will just be able to listen for the event and receive the parameters in the handler).

Comment: If I add an additional selection manually, using the relative tool in the dialogue bar, the points of all selections are included in the array of selected points. This is why I think the trigger for including the points is the `plotly_selected` event, maybe I'm wrong.

PS: I've edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: Could you post a runnable version which presents this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged all the data emitted by the events in the plotly library, which should be as follows:

```
plotly_afterexport
plotly_afterplot
plotly_animated
plotly_animating
plotly_animatingframe
plotly_animationinterrupted
plotly_autosize
plotly_beforeexport
plotly_buttonclicked
plotly_click
plotly_clickannotation
plotly_deselect
plotly_doubleclick
plotly_framework
plotly_hover
plotly_react
plotly_redraw
plotly_relayout
plotly_relayouting
plotly_restyle
plotly_selected
plotly_selecting
plotly_sliderchange
plotly_sliderend
plotly_sliderstart
plotly_transitioned
plotly_transitioning
plotly_transitioninterrupted
plotly_unhover
plotly_update
plotly_webglcontextlost
```

Exploring the event data of the `plotly_react` event, which I use to draw and update the chart, I found the `selectedpoints` inside the `data` object:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "x": [
                0.01,
                ...,
                100
            ],
            "y": [
                0.0006,
                ...,
                0
            ],
            "mode": "markers",
            "selectedpoints": [
                4182,
                ...,
                4365
            ]
        }
    ],
    "layout": {
        "showlegend": false,
        "dragmode": "select",
        "shapes": [
            {
                "editable": true,
                "xref": "x",
                "yref": "y",
                "layer": "above",
                "opacity": 0.5,
                "line": {
                    "color": "#444",
                    "width": 4,
                    "dash": "solid"
                },
                "fillcolor": "green",
                "fillrule": "evenodd",
                "type": "rect",
                "x0": 39.021639200761186,
                "y0": 0.4910903426791277,
                "x1": 46.663120456707894,
                "y1": 0.3875887850467289
            }
        ],
        "selections": [
            {
                "editable": true,
                "xref": "x",
                "yref": "y",
                "layer": "above",
                "opacity": 0.5,
                "line": {
                    "color": "#444",
                    "width": 4,
                    "dash": "solid"
                },
                "fillcolor": "green",
                "fillrule": "evenodd",
                "type": "rect",
                "x0": 39.021639200761186,
                "y0": 0.4910903426791277,
                "x1": 46.663120456707894,
                "y1": 0.3875887850467289
            }
        ],
        "xaxis": {
            "type": "linear",
            "range": [
                -5.809272121788773,
                105.81927212178877
            ],
            "autorange": true
        },
        "yaxis": {
            "type": "linear",
            "range": [
                -1.1214953271028036,
                1.1214953271028036
            ],
            "autorange": true
        },
        "autosize": true
    }
}
```

So in order to grab the selected points of the chart, using the built in selection function, is it sufficient to iterate trough each data objects (if more than a single trace is present) and merging the relative `selectedpoints` in an array of all selected points, e.g. `wholeSelectedPoints`.

```
var wholeSelectedPoints = [];

plotly_react_eventData['data'].forEach(element => {
    wholeSelectedPoints = [...wholeSelectedPoints, ...element['selectedpoints']]
});

console.log(wholeSelectedPoints);
// [object Array] (4)
// [4182,4365,10,20]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just getting points in your known rectangle from the point array that you already know?

```js
var N = 100;

function randomArray() {
  var output = new Array(N);
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    output[i] = Math.random();
  }
  return output;
}

var myPlot = document.getElementById("plotly-graph");

var settings = [
  {
    mode: "markers",
    x: randomArray(),
    y: randomArray()
  }
];

var layout = {};

var config = {};

Plotly.newPlot(myPlot, settings, layout, config);

function getPointsInRectangle(rect) {
  var xData = settings[0].x;
  var yData = settings[0].y;

  var selectedPoints = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < xData.length; i++) {
    if (
      xData[i] >= rect.x0 &&
      xData[i] <= rect.x1 &&
      yData[i] >= rect.y0 &&
      yData[i] <= rect.y1
    ) {
      selectedPoints.push({ x: xData[i], y: yData[i] });
    }
  }

  return selectedPoints;
}

var rect = {
  x0: 0.1,
  x1: 0.2,
  y0: 0.1,
  y1: 0.2
};

var selectedPoints = getPointsInRectangle(rect);
console.log(selectedPoints);
```

```html
<!-- Plotly.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 800px; height: 500px;" id="plotly-graph"></div>
```

This should work :

```js
/* all the code from your question is here */

myPlot.on("plotly_selected", function(eventData) {
  var selectedPoints = eventData.points;
  console.log(selectedPoints);
});

// Programmatically trigger the selection event
var eventData = {points: selectedPoints};
myPlot.emit('plotly_selected', eventData);
```

Comment: I would like to use the builtin function for the selection, it seems strange to me that it's impossible to use them, and I gues is coulb be just a matter of triggering an event

Comment: @drypatrick You are right. I added the code that theoretically should work, but it does not... I am not a "plotly" expert, just trying to help.

Comment: What builtin function are you talking about ? As I said in the comment above, triggering the plotly_selected event won't do anything magically since it's up to the event emitter to provide the relevant data that are passed to the event handler(s), so  triggering that event implies your code has already transformed a rectangle shape into an actual selection of points, which is what @Anton suggests, but still the selection in that case is not "real" because Plotly is not aware of it (it doesn't listen for those events but only fires them).

Comment: If you want to replicate what happens when the user draws a rectangle with the select2d tool, including drawing the select box, highlighting selected points and firing the plotly_selected event, then you need to emit a mouse drag event (simulate the user drawing the select box), not the plotly_selected event.

Comment: @EricLavault I'm referring to the builtin selection function, any hint on how can I emit a mouse drag event?